# how to export correctly accented words with mongoexport

Tags: mongodb

I want to export a collection in .csv format by using next command in mongodb:

```
mongoexport --db voypluscab --collection rides_driver --fields driver_name,email,total_viajes,promedio_estrellas --type=csv --out "$PATH_REPORTES/viajes_conductor_`date +"%d-%m-%y-%H:%M:%S"`.csv"
```

But when I open the file it shows words like this:

[image]

I want this to display "García" instead of "GarcÃ­a" and "Jesús" instead of  "JesÃºs"

---

UPDATE: The problem was encoding, I ran this:

```
file --mime-encoding test.csv
```

it shows

```
test.csv: utf-8
```

so I had to change encoding to iso-8859-1 by running next command:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 test.csv > out.csv
```

then I open the archive with excel and now it shows it properly

[image]

Comment: are u using windows or linux ?

Comment: I'm currently using Linux

Comment: @JesúsAyala Did you open the csv file on linux with Libre Office or what?